# Does having over 80% dynamic and rapidly changing content affect SEO?

Tags: seo, dynamic

I have a website that pulls promotions of products from other website.

My index page has a structure similar to this:

1. My Brand - Best Promotions
2. ## Looking for great deals? Check out our top promotions
3. A menu - listing the promotions categories
4. 20 of the latest promotions (the best ones):
   I list an image;
   Promotion description (200 chars);
   Link to the promotion page.

**Question:**

More then 80% of my index page (maybe even 90%) is composed of the 20 promotions I list; these promotions change on a daily bases -> which dramatically changes the content of my index page.

**Does the dynamic changing of the index page affect SEO?**

Should I try to add more static text where I can? (which won't change)

Ty

Answer (score 1):

If the topic or category of the content on your home page is drastically changing, Google really doesn't know what to rank your home page for so be sure to set a good title, and description, and try and have some static copy on your home page which isn't changing that Google can use to help rank your site.

You may want to categorize the promotions so that you have a page with electronics for example and when they update it's still electronic content/copy on that category page.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [semantic web syntax](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html) and [sitemaps](http://www.sitemaps.org/), search engines will not be clueless about your content and will understand that essentially it remains the same and only the details are changing.